# python join list 2 to list 1 line by line

Tags: python, string, list

I have 2 lists of strings and need to join the lists so the line from list 2 is appended to the end of each line of list 1. the sorting is correct and there is the same number of records in each list. example below:

```
list1 =  ["A", "B" , "C"]

list2 = ["E", "F", "G"]

newlist = ["A,E", "B,F", "C,G"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just simply zip the lists and then join the tuples:

```
>>> list1 =  ["A", "B" , "C"]
>>> list2 = ["E", "F", "G"]
>>> [','.join(i) for i in zip(list1, list2)]
['A,E', 'B,F', 'C,G']
```

Comment: I think, this is the best answer, taking also into account that it's easily generalised to arbitrary number of lists.

Answer (score 3):

Easy task, use `map`:

```
In[4]: list1 = ["A", "B" , "C"]

list2 = ["E", "F", "G"]
In[5]: newlist = map(lambda x, y: x+","+y, list1, list2)
In[6]: newlist
Out[6]: ['A,E', 'B,F', 'C,G']
```

you can even, generate it for general lenght purpouse:

```
def joinWithComma(*args):
    return ",".join(args)

In[15]: newlist = map(joinWithComma, list1, list2, list1, list2)
In[16]: newlist
Out[16]: ['A,E,A,E', 'B,F,B,F', 'C,G,C,G']
```

Comment: or imap from itertools. I support this approach.

Answer (score 2):

You could combine the incredible power of list comprehensions and built-in `zip` function:

```
In [1]: list1 =  ["A", "B" , "C"]

In [2]: list2 = ["E", "F", "G"]

In [3]: [a + ',' + b for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]
Out[3]: ['A,E', 'B,F', 'C,G']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have more than one list, this will do :

```
list_of_list = [list1,list2]
[",".join(n) for n in  zip( *list_of_list )]
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine

```
list1 = ["A", "B" , "C"]
list2 = ["E", "F", "G"]
newlist = []
for i in range(0, len(list1)):
    newlist.append(list1[i]+","+list2[i])
print(newlist)

bash@bash:~$ python a.py 
['A,E', 'B,F', 'C,G']
```